# git merge master branch to release branch issues

Tags: github

I've accidentally did some changes directly on my master branch. How do I safely merge my master back in to my release branch without loosing any changes that were done on either the master (which were done by me) and on the release branch, there were changes done by my colleagues in that branch. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Release branch and merge master.

```
git checkout release-blah-branch
git merge master
```

If the changes will merge without collisions you are done.